# How to fill in the rest of this square with faces

Tags: edit-mode

What would be the most efficient way to fill in this square with faces in and around the spiral pattern?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Fill* option (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) will fill your selection with triangles :

In *Edge Mode*, select outer edges : [image: spiral_01]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to fill with triangles : [image: spiral_02]

Clean by hand if needed : [image: spiral_03]

Comment: i want quads. not triangles 

Comment: haha we all do. But with complex shapes like yours, proper topology almost always requires manual adjustments. Filling with tris gets you halfway.

Comment: easier than expected!! THanks alot!

Comment: @holybobine: I have noticed that there are alot of Intersect Faces 528 via the 3D-print geometry check tool